# How to extract variables from boolean logic expression in python

Tags: python, string, extract

I want to extract variables from boolean logic expression

ex)
Input: `E= A or B or (C and not D) -> String` 
Output: `['E', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D'] -> List`

Comment: Is the input a string of Python code, or something else? If it' something else, what are the rules? For example, do variables have to be a single uppercase character? (And is there anything else that could be uppercase?)

Comment: Your question is not clear. What exactly is your input: a string?

Comment: If it's meant to be a string of Python code: `[n.id for n in ast.walk(ast.parse(inp)) if isinstance(n, ast.Name)]`. See [the `ast` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html) for details (and I'm sure you'll have questions after you work through the basics).

Comment: @abarnert This may help explain his question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50145932/how-to-code-canalization-of-boolean-value-in-python#50145932

Comment: @HarisNadeem Thanks—but even after reading that question, I'm not sure whether this is meant to be a string of Python code or some other vaguely similar grammar.

Comment: @abarnert I believe it is a python code where his variables are boolean and he wishes to output a list of those variables casted as a string. But of course only he can confirm whether that really is the case

Comment: Anyway, it sounds like your larger problem is that you want to parse some simple language—which may be a strict subset of Python, or may just be coincidentally kind of similar. But either way, just asking how to extract specific strings out of it isn't going to do you any good. To solve your other problem, you need to build a parse tree. And, once you do that, it will solve this problem automatically—whether you use `ast`, or a parsing library like `pyparsing`, or a pgen like `PLY`, or a simple custom OP parser, it will be trivial to get the variable names out of the tree.

Answer (score 0):

If your expressions and variable names are as simple as your example suggests, this might work:

```
import re

string = 'E = A or B or (C and not D)'

variables = list(filter(None, re.split(r'[^A-Z]+', string)))

print(variables)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
['E', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score -1):

With re (works with string inputs now):

```
inp = "E= random or andy"
#inp = "E= A or B or (C and not D)"

logic = ["xor","or","and","not","=",")","(",""," "]
outp = re.split(r'(=|\)|\(| )', inp)
outp = [x for x in outp if x not in logic ]

print(outp)
```

Comment: Will not work for more complex cases like `'random or andy'`

Answer (score -2):

You could use `split()` and `join()` as in

```
s='E= A or B or (C and not D)'
s=''.join( c for c in s if  c not in '=()' )
l = []
for x in s.split():
    if(x not in ['or', 'and', not']):
        l.append(x)
print(l)
```

`join()` is used to remove the parenthesis and `=` sign.

Output:

```
['E', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
```

Comment: You should also take into account `E=` and parenthesis

Comment: Even if you fix the obvious syntax error, this is really hacky and fragile. Sure, it happens to work with the OP's exact test case, but if that's all that matters, you could just do `l = ['E', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D']` and be done with it. I don't think it's possible to write a good answer to this question without more info from the OP.

Comment: @soon I removed them with `join()`. Is there a better way?

Comment: @J...S I think replace is more suitable here instead of filter + join

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: @soon Why is `replace()` better? With it we have to call it for every character. Isn't it?

Comment: It is more idiomatic. `join` is often used when you want to concat several stings with a separator (e.g. space, comma). And you can use `re.sub` and `re.split`, both of them allows you to specify regex.